# Autoscale the Vertical Axis in Google Sheets Chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to automatically adjust the vertical axis boundaries to the changing data?
[image]

I know that I can manually change the lower bound:
[image]
But I do not know how to do it automatically using google sheets or using google apps script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this one in Apps Script:

#### Script:

```
function createEmbeddedLineChart() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var yAxis = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!A2:A4');
  var xAxis = sheet.getRange('Sheet1!B2:B4');
  var yAxisValues = yAxis.getValues().flat();

  // set lower and higher bound to be 100 away from max and min values (e.g. 100)
  var offset = 100;
  var minVal = Math.min.apply(Math, yAxisValues) - offset;
  var maxVal = Math.max.apply(Math, yAxisValues) + offset;

  // apply calculated bounds to vAxis min and max values
  var vAxisOptions = {
    minValue: minVal,
    maxValue: maxVal
  }
  
  var lineChartBuilder = sheet.newChart().asLineChart();
  var chart = lineChartBuilder
    .addRange(xAxis)
    .addRange(yAxis)
    .setPosition(3, 3, 0, 0)
    .setOption('vAxis', vAxisOptions)
    .build();
 
  sheet.insertChart(chart);  
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- Lower and upper bounds will automatically adjust 100 away from the minimum and maximum value of `yAxis` values respectively.
- You can adjust the distance (offset) from the minimum and maximum values depending on what you need. I set it to 100 to mimic the sample you gave above.
- To automatically update the chart's upper/lower bounds upon modifying the yAxis values, you might need to use triggers and recreate the chart whenever the yAxis range is updated.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know what method I can use instead of asLineChart to get a timeline chart with hours and minutes? I can't find any documentation about the supported date and time formats.

Comment: Hi @dereks, I haven't personally tried a timeline with hours and minutes, but you can see an application [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline). It shows a chart with hours and minutes there. Based on the usage, I think the date/time should be a date object. Not sure what other supported formats are. But check the link for more details.

Comment: If you still have question regarding the timeline, I guess a new post would be best as it is a bit different compared to the question here and it will allow other people to provide a clearer answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!